# What are some of the database optimizations for multi-tenant applications

Tags: sql-server, oracle, nhibernate, optimization, cloud

Salesforce’s secret sauce: It queries its databases with “The Multi-Tenant Optimizer" So exactly what could this practice be comprised of?

Comment: It's proprietary, according to the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.salesforce.com/community/crm-best-practices/dreamforce08-developer-sessions/2008-tdf-plattech-multitenant-magic.jsp) a link to one of their webinars, where their chief architect talked about their database architecture.

Answer (score 4):

A whole lot of marketing.

Answer (score 2):

Denormalizing the data so that every row has the "tenant id" in it which reduces the number of necessary joins that have to be done to find the owner of the data.
Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Patent application is [here](http://www.patentgenius.com/patent/7529728.html) 
Broadly, separate stats for each tenant/user.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use "Sharding".   Here is a link which has a fairly good description of this technique :

http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/

If you're using hibernate for Object-Relational Persistence, they have an additional library which adds support for sharding (and insulates the application many of the details) :

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html